# API response data showing brackets when displayed (vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a manyTomany field (**panelists**) within my response that, when displayed, the values are inside brackets. i couldn't find a way to retract only the values/remove the brackets as I do the display with a v-for.

step-program is a component I created in my Vue project:

```
<step-program
 v-for="(item, index) in programs" :item="program" :key="index"
 :start_time="item.start_time| formatDate"
 :end_time="item.end_time| formatDate"
 :topic ="item.topic"
 :panelNames="item.panelists">
</step-program>
```

Here is the axios code :

```
mounted() {
  axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/programs/")
    .then(response => {
      this.programs = response.data
    })

    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

This is the result I get :
[panelists result in brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO9YU.png)

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably just use {{panelNames}} inside `<step-program>` component , which is not single string, but array of strings. You can 
1.In your code change this array to single string :panelNames="item.panelists.join(', ')"
2.Inside `<step-program>` use v-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by iterating `panelNames` props in the child component as `item.panelists` is an array and can be iterable further. Hence, from parent pass this as an array and iterate in child as per the requirement.

Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['topic', 'panelNames'],
  template: `<div><h4> {{ topic }} </h4>
                     <ul v-for="(name, index) in panelNames" :key="index">
                    <li>{{ name }}</li>
             </ul></div>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        programs: [{
        topic: 'Topic A',
        panelists: ['Panel 1', 'Panel 2']
      }, {
        topic: 'Topic B',
        panelists: ['Panel 3', 'Panel 4']
      }, {
        topic: 'Topic C',
        panelists: ['Panel 5', 'Panel 6']
      }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child v-for="(item, index) in programs"
         :key="index"
         :topic="item.topic"
         :panel-names="item.panelists">
  </child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because each `item` inside `this.programs` is an array.

Use v-for inside `<step-program/>` component to loop through an array

```
<p v-for="(string, id) in items" :key="id">
{{string}}
</p>
```